# Choosing ubuntu version for 10 year old pc

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I am going to install Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS (Lucid Lynx) on my 10 year old pc. So should I have to install by **Desktop CD** or **Server install CD**? And what happens to my partitions while installing Ubuntu in my winxp pc permanently?

Comment: That version is not supported. Install Lubuntu 14.04 instead.

Comment: yaeh!!! i have pc with 512 mb ram with pentium4 !!!!what to do now???

Comment: 10.04 recently went end-of-life and is not supported any more. You have to use a more current version like 14.04 or at least 12.04 (active for about 2 more years), if your hardware is not supported any more by 14.04. Chose desktop version, if you want a graphical user interface, server if you want to operate with a terminal only(!). Note that normal Ubuntu with Unity Desktop needs probably too much resources for you, so better take Lubuntu with LXDE Desktop which is more lightweight. And the installer will do what you chose. It can nuke your whole disk or install into free unpartitioned space.

Comment: Thankyou started downloading lubuntu!But what happens to my partisions like Local disk-D,Local disk-E when i install lubantu? Thankyou!

Comment: Xubuntu and Lubuntu should run happily on your machine. When you install ubuntu you have the option to install alongside, overwrite, or custom partitioning - the first shrinks the existing partitions, the second overwrites, the last is up to you. Make sure you back up your data to another machine before doing anything though.

Answer (score 0):

For a system with 512 MB of RAM I can only recommend distros with lightweight desktop environment (DE), such as Lubuntu, that sports LXDE (where L stands for Lightweight). It's preferable to install rather newer versions of OS as it usually supports more hardware. So I would recommend Lubuntu 14.04 LTS (Long Term Support = till 2019, but you can upgrade every two years) or something similar like PeppermintOS 5/6 (both based on 14.04). There is also WattOS with LXDE based on 14.04 and they have even some "Microwatt" edition for even slower, older PCs.

Other lightweight DE choices include fluxbox, various tiling like xmonad, ratpoison, awesome etc. But if you want something more familiar LXDE is probably the best first choice.

Lastly I'd like to mention that elementaryOS Luna is quite lightweight actually although it's build on older Ubuntu base (12.04). Too bad this is not true for their new version Freya, which didn't run properly even on Atom netbook with 1 GB RAM. Still Luna is supported till April 2017 so you might give it a try too.

Comment: for what to do during installation you may want to check out Ubuntu Wiki: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

Answer (score -1):

**Hey there!**

10.04 comes with an application called **Gparted**. You can use it to manage partitions from the live media. So I think live installation is your best bet, plus you get to test the waters of Ubuntu on your old hardware first. Also a prompt will appear when you install 10.04 that asks you to partition your HD with gparted, so at some point during the live CD installation, you will run into gparted.

There is also the option of backing up all of your XP files and software and running it in a virtual machine, if you have your XP installation media. This way you can keep XP in ubuntu. I'd post an image of how to's but this is my first post.

In my opinion, go with LXDE or Xubuntu so you can have recent software on your old hardware. Its awesome. But 10.04 isn't too bad if you know how to manage your packages but not much support will be available.

Comment: Installing 10.04 is not a good idea if you want the new software to work and the latest security fixes. It also is [no longer supported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) so [off-topic](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) here as well